# iOS app to map Wi-Fi signals?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an app like [OpenSignal](http://opensignal.com) but for mapping Wi-Fi signals around my apartment. I have also tried using [NetSpot](http://www.netspotapp.com) on my Mac but I would really like a mobile app to take advantage of GPS location and automatic data collection rather than fumbling around with a manual process.

Does anyone know of an app that can do this?

Comment: If you get answers that aren't what you seek, consider reviewing http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation and add explicit requirements rather than only linking to tools that have dozens of features (keep the link, but explain precisely what functions you want and need)

Answer (score 1):

The Fing network scanner is the tool I'd use. You'll have to pay their upgrade to get syncing of the data and some advanced tools, but the free capabilities allow you to tap on the SSID and then geo-locate the device for the scanning and save the results for later review when you are elsewhere.

[image]

As for making colorful maps, that isn't something I've seen on an iOS map. You can collect that data for free using Airport Utility - but it's not geo-located and certainly not accurate over the ranges WiFi degrades.

You'd want to get a tool like AeroHive software and hardware to do enough measurements to map signal levels in a building or network area. Pretty much any enterprise managed WiFi solution has this.